# jQuery-UI Dialog Widget - Limit number of times allowed to be triggered

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

Is there a way to limit to the number of times a dialog box is triggered to appear until the page is reloaded? Specifically, I am using the jQuery UI Dialog Widget. I was hoping there was some way of feeding this into the options of the widget - I imagine it would look something like

```
// div#notice is the name of the dialog element, 
// with style="display:none" by default
$("#notice").dialog({
    dialogClass: "noticeDialog",
        buttons: [{
            text: "OK",
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }],
        repeat: 1 // A Dialog option equivalent to this does not exist to
                  // my knowledge
 }
```

The only way I can think of achieving this is for the dialog box to .remove() itself from the DOM inside the 'close' option callback function. Something like:

```
$(".selector").dialog({
    close: function() {
        $(#"dialogBox").remove();
    }
});
```

I have a feeling this will not work as hoped, however. What better options are there? If there is a way to set a timeout on the dialog box, that would also be helpful and/or accomplish a similar effect.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-destroy

Comment: Nothing I can think of. Put the counter in the code that triggers the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in the code that triggers the dialog. First, initialize a counter:

```
var dialog_counter = 0;
var dialog_limit = 5;
```

Then in the code that displays the dialog, increment and test it:

```
if (++dialog_counter <= dialog_limit) {
    $("#notice").dialog({
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of using a counter, but it it doesn't really work in this case because the code that triggers the dialog is contained within an else-if loop inside another callback function, i.e.
    $(selector).blur(function() {
        if(condition) {
            // some code
        } else if(condition) {
            $("#notice").dialog({
                // init options
            });
        }
    });

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Just make sure the counter variable is in the containing scope of all the functions that trigger the dialog.

Comment: The counter idea worked. The counter must be initialized outside of the .blur() function, then add the clause "&& if counter === 0" to the "if" condition inside the .blur() callback. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why you need to add that. If the counter is 0, then `++counter <= limit` should be true.